# Disable Reply and Reply to all outlook options in Java

Tags: java, vba, outlook

My application is Java based web application and I have a requirement here to send private email to the employee of the organization. Here I need to disable *Reply*, *Reply to all* and *forward* options on Outlook.  As per my understanding these things can be done through manipulating macros but I'm not sure if we can do this through Java code or not. I'm looking for you valuable suggestions here.

I have just started working over it but could not find any generic solution over it.

Thanks in advance.
I have s

Comment: Did I understand right that you want to disable the "Reply" etc. buttons on the recipients Outlook by sending a mail to him? That's not possible due to security restrictions. (If this is not what you want then your question is unclear … at least to me).

Comment: Yes this is what i exactly want. i am expecting something like sending macros with email content with changes the outlook macro setting for that particular email. i have got some details about paid Aspose api which might handle these things but not very sure as did not see any sample code which can do this.

Answer (score -1):

If this was possible, then this would be a **huge** security issue!

Gladly it is not possible and you cannot manipulate a recipients Outlook by sending him an email containing macros.

This is easy to answer as "not possible", because this would be a security issue if person A could manipulate the Outlook of person B by sending an email to person B.